# FishEye lens calibration giving Distortion Matrix Zero

Tags: c++

I am using fisheye::calibrate( ) function to get Intrinsic Parameters of camera, with this I am getting camera matrix, but Distortions matrix is null.

```
cv::Matx33d cameraMatrix;
cv::Vec4d distCoeffs;
std::vector<cv::Vec3d> R;
std::vector<cv::Vec3d> T;
int flag = 0;
//flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;
//flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND;
//flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW;

rms = cv::fisheye::calibrate(objpoints, imgpoints, imgSize,cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, R, T,flag, cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6));
```

This is the output I am getting with above code snippet.

```
**cameraMatrix : [407.4366543152521, 0, 479.5;
 0, 407.4366543152521, 639.5;
 0, 0, 1]
distCoeffs : [0, 0, 0, 0]**
```

Dont know,  why I am getting distortion matrix with zero values.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.
This is a known issue with OpenCV's fisheye calibration.

https://github.com/DavidTorresOcana/image_pipeline/issues/1

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7008

Image correspondences appearing in the corners of the image will cause the calibration procedure to silently fail. You can add the flag `fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND`, which will throw an error when this condition occurs (but will not skip the problematic image or fix the underlying issue).